# problem with performance ngxs and redux dev tools

Tags: ngxs, redux-devtools-extension

I store a whole app in ngxs and this works fine.

I have problem when I want to see these data in redux devtools.
On first when store was small, all works fine, when store comes lager reduxdevtools works slower and slower, and now is crashes.

Actual here is my [json store](https://github.com/Areen3/archive/blob/master/example.json) 
it is no so big, but in feature with data from backend it will be have about 20-30 Mb

on debug window I see these info:
Application state or actions payloads are too large making Redux DevTools serialization slow and consuming a lot of memory.  See  [link to article](https://git.io/fpcP5) on how to configure it.

But these example is under ngrx.

I think, that probem is with serialization large object in devtools.

Is it possible to control which areas should be shown in devtools using ngxs as in the example from the link above? or maybe these are better tools for example:[diff monitor](https://github.com/whetstone/redux-devtools-diff-monitor)

thanks for ansvers...

Comment: having similar problem. and our store is only ~5MB. the example to sanitize seems to not be sufficient.